# Using wildcards with counter

Tags: python

I am counting certain words in a bunch of .txt files. How can I use wildcards to get the count? Here is my code so far. This will only work if I change my list to include full words, like "achieve" instead of "achiev".

```
import csv
import glob
import re

TARGET_FILES = r'C:/Users/smans/Documents/Docs/*.*'

OUTPUT_FILE = r'C:/Users/smans/Documents/Output.csv'

OUTPUT_FIELDS = ['file name,', 'twords', 'compete']

COMPETE = {'achiev', 'acqui', 'agress', 'agreem'}

def main():
    f_out = open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(f_out, lineterminator='\n')
    wr.writerow(OUTPUT_FIELDS)

    file_list = glob.glob(TARGET_FILES)
    for file in file_list:
        print(file)
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as f_in:
            doc = f_in.read()
        doc = doc.lower()
        output_data = get_data(doc)
        output_data[0] = file
        wr.writerow(output_data)

def get_data(doc):
    _odata = [0] * 3
   
    tokens = re.findall('\w(?:[-\w]*\w)?', doc)
    for token in tokens:
        if not token.isdigit():
            _odata[1] += 1
        count = 2
        for word in COMPETE:
            if token in word:
                _odata[count] += 1
            count += 1
    return _odata
```

Comment: Wildcards at the beginning? or at the end? or in the middle?

Comment: Sorry about that. At the end.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Comment: `if any(token.startswith(pattern) for pattern in COMPETE):`

Comment: `_odata[count] += any(token.startswith(pattern) for pattern in COMPETE)`